# Best way to pass arrays of data back to server (on post)?

Tags: php, html, asp.net-mvc, http, post

Whats the best way of storing arrays in post data?

At the moment im generating a CSV and storing it in a hidden control..

This seems kinda cludgey..

Is there a better way?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel,

this will largely depend on the target webserver and whether javascript is being used. however, you don't tag with javascript, so will ignore the possibilities there which include JSON, as well as serialised javascript arrays.

your best bet might be to look at javascript as an option if at all possible.

using psuedo-code as an example, you could do something like (traditional $POST):

use the [] symbol in the name of the form field you are submitting like:

```
<input type="text" name ="whatever[]" value="a" />
<input type="text" name ="whatever[]" value="b" />
<input type="text" name ="whatever[]" value="c" />
<input type="text" name ="whatever[]" value="d" />
```

when you post, this will come in as

```
$whatever = $_POST['whatever'];
```

and you can access them like:

```
$whatever[0]
```

which will yield you "a".

i know it's sketchy and it's not how i'd generally do it in .net, but is hopefully a generic non js appraoch that's transeferable.

Comment: While JSON is named after JavaScript, it is actually language independent.

Comment: good point Aether. the independence tho is in relation to the server that consumes it (i.e. .net, php, java etc). it is actually a subset of javascript and therefore requires that (js) be running on the client in order to function clientside...

Answer (score 2):

I would use [JSON](http://www.json.org/). That makes it trivial to turn it back into an array or object collection server side.